# Excel Macro conditional formatting indirect cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I'm a little inexperienced with Excel, but I'll try my best to explain what I'm trying to do:

I'm working in Excel 2010, and I'm trying to have a macro do an addition based on the number in a column.

For example, I want to have the macro add a value based on the name in the B column and the number in the C column. For the name "02 Gloves-DISC" in the B column, I wanted to add the following based on the value in the C column: if it's <5, +8.83. if it's <10, +7.  if it's <20, +5. if it's <30, +3. if it's <40, +1. if it's <56, +.50.

I had something similar to this, but I could not get it to do the search and calculation for each row:

```
Selection.Replace What:="02 Gloves-DISC", Replacement:="=IF(C2<5, C2+8.83, IF(C2<10, C2+7, IF(C2<20, C2+5, IF(C2<30, C2+3, IF(C2<40, C2+1, C2+.5)))))", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I hope this info helps. Thank you in advance for any help. I've read about the R1C1 reference, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Here is an example of the data I'm working with:

```
SKU         ClassName           TakeItPrice
HJC10569002 02 Gloves-DISC          38.93
HJC1222066  02 Gloves-DISC          49.491
HJC1224011  02 Gloves-DISC          40.491
HJC1228062  02 Gloves-DISC          36.991
HJC152100   01 First Class-DISC 13.191
HJC152200   01 First Class-DISC 26.99
HJC152202   01 First Class-DISC 31.491
HJC180000   01 First Class-DISC 11.891
HJC190005   01 First Class-DISC 11.891
HJC350005   01 First Class-DISC 11.891
```

Comment: Why not just add a column for discount and calculate it with your formula?

Comment: I assume you want the new value to be inserted into a new column.  Reason I assume this is if you run the macro multiple times eventually everything will be >= 56 because if you keep running it you lose the original starting value and would eventualyl get to + .50 on everything over and over and over...

Comment: running the macro with the addition is a one time thing. I actually will have a separate line in the macro for each of the 'classname'. each classname group will have different amounts to add to the 'takeitprice'. the 'DISC' part in there is actually part of the classname. there is also the smae classname, but without the 'DISC'. sorry if that part was a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Two macros for you.. the second is a generic one I use to find the last row of data in a sheet.

```
Public Sub addDisc()
   Dim Class As Long
   Dim Price
   Dim myRow

   For myRow = 2 To xlLastRow(ActiveSheet.Name)   'Optional to find last row
     Class = CLng(Left(Cells(myRow, 2), 2))
     If Class < 5 Then
        Cells(myRow, 3) = Cells(myRow, 3) + 8.83
     ElseIf Class < 10 Then
        Cells(myRow, 3) = Cells(myRow, 3) + 7
     ElseIf Class < 20 Then
        Cells(myRow, 3) = Cells(myRow, 3) + 5
     ElseIf Class < 30 Then
        Cells(myRow, 3) = Cells(myRow, 3) + 3
     ElseIf Class < 40 Then
        Cells(myRow, 3) = Cells(myRow, 3) + 1
     ElseIf Class < 56 Then
        Cells(myRow, 3) = Cells(myRow, 3) + 0.5
     End If
   Next myRow
End Sub


Public Function xlLastRow(Optional WorksheetName As String) As Long
   '    find the last populated row in a worksheet
   If WorksheetName = vbNullString Then WorksheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
      With Worksheets(WorksheetName)
        On Error Resume Next
        xlLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(1), xlFormulas, _
        xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        If Err <> 0 Then xlLastRow = 0
      End With
End Function
```